# on change of a value in one dropdown should make an ajax call using JSON and get data and loaded into store of another dropdown

Tags: extjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load the store of one dropdown on change of value in another dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859524/load-the-store-of-one-dropdown-on-change-of-value-in-another-dropdown)

On change of a value in one dropdown should make an ajax call using JSON and get data and loaded into store of another dropdown in EXTjs. Please post the code to be written in EXTjs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
firstDropdown.onChange(function(firstValue) {
    var dataFromServer = ajax.getData(firstValue);
    secondCombo.getStore().loadData(dataFromServer);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I wrote the following code: var FUNCTION_NAME_Field = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    id: 'funcId',
    fieldLabel: 'Function',
    store: functionNameStore,
    displayField: 'name',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        select: function (combo, record) {
        alert('hi');
            agentNameStore.setProxy({type: 'ajax', 
                url: '/omsWeb/navigation/getAgent.htm',
                extraParams: {
                    id: 'test'
                }
            });
         
        }
    }

Comment: Here, FUNCTION_NAME_Field -> 1st dropdown, agentNameStore->store of second dropdown where data has to be loaded. Getting response but data not loaded into combobox. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try `agentNameStore.load()` after setting proxy, perhaps?  This looks like Ext4, which we haven't switched to at work yet, so I'm not as versed.  Perhaps a bug even... make sure you are using the latest version of Ext4.